# floating a div aligning next to another

Tags: html, css

I want the plus signs to align right, however it just weird once zoomed out. It's not near the actual text.

I tried a `float: right` however it's just not exactly next to the text. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Menu]

CSS:

```
span.title {
    display: inline-block;
}

span.toggle {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="subMenu">
    <i class="lock"></i> 
    <span class="title">User </span>
    <span class="toggle">+</span>                                   
</li>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2x1vcpo/)

When I do

```
span.title {
    padding-right: 12%
}
```

it shows this:

[image: Menu]

However it doesn't align them all on one side. Do you guys know what it is that I'm doing wrong? am I used the floats wrong?

Comment: Guess your fiddle is working good. :\

Comment: yeah but but it's too far out. I need it to be in the container next to "User Account"

Answer (score 0):

I edited your css as I understand you I hope this is what you want :)

```css
#side-navigation li {
 padding: 8px 5px 5px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.lock {
    background: url('../images/icon.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
}

.subMenu-link {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

li.subMenu span{
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.subMenu:hover {
 background: #191919;
}

#side-navigation li:hover {
 color: white;
}

li:hover .lock{
 background: url("") no-repeat center;  
}

span.title {
    margin:0;
 display: inline-block;
}

span.toggle {
 position:relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
span{
    float:left;
}
li{float:left;
clear:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the element with the id "side-navigation" is an ul:

```
#side-navigation { float: left; clear: both; list-style: none; }
span.title { padding-right: 1em; }
span.toggle { float: right; }
```

Result (without the other CSS selectors):

[image: result]